# Every 5 items in array, not every 5th item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a table consisting of multiple rows. Each row contains 5 data cells and the innerHTML of each cell is different:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
    <td>Data 4</td>
    <td>Data 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Data 6</td>
    <td>Data 7</td>
    <td>Data 8</td>
    <td>Data 9</td>
    <td>Data 10</td>
</tr>
...
```

**JavaScript**

The below code gets the data from the first 5 cells, but I need to loop through all rows and then each cell within each row.

```
var allTableData = [];
var tableData = $('td');

_.each(tableData, (data, i) => {
    if (i < 5) {
        allTableData.push(data.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

**My desired output is:**

```
values: [
    ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4', 'Data 5'], 
    ['Data 6', 'Data 7', 'Data 8', 'Data 9', 'Data 10'], 
    [...]
];
```

How would I get my desired output with JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: You will need nested loops. The first loop loops through all the `<tr>` tags and then a loop inside of that loop loops through all the `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do two levels of `.map()`:

```
var arr = $('table tr').get().map(function(tr) {
  return $('td', tr).get().map(function(td) {
    return $(td).html();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gbgjhj83/

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `tr`s, and inside that loop, iterate over the `td`s.

```js
var allTableData = [];
var rowData = [];
var tableRows = $('#myTable tr');
var row;

tableRows.each(function() {
  rowCells = $(this).find('td');
  rowCells.each(function() {
    rowData.push($(this).text());
  });
  allTableData.push(_.clone(rowData));
  rowData.length = 0;
});

console.log(allTableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
    <td>Data 4</td>
    <td>Data 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 6</td>
    <td>Data 7</td>
    <td>Data 8</td>
    <td>Data 9</td>
    <td>Data 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzekdy23/2/